# Create timeline from data in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few tables in my script that I need to create a timeline from all of them. The main tables are "posts" - "likes" - "comments".

posts table has rows: PID - UID - title - time_added.
likes table has rows: LID - PID - UID - time_added.
comments table has rows: CID - PID - UID - time_added.
users table has rows: UID - username.

I'm creating a page in the users' profiles called: "Timeline". It should show the actions of the user sorted by time. UID refers to the user ID.

Data example while browsing that page:

1. User Commented on Post xxxx at xxx_time_added_xxx.
2. User Liked post xxxx at xxx_time_added_xxx.
3. User added Post xxxx at xxx_time_added_xxx.

1. Is there's a way or MySQL query that can combine all these tables and arrange them by time_added?
2. I thought of creating a new MySQL table: user_timeline that has rows:

   ```
   TID - UID - PID - LID - CID
   ```

   And after each action (Post, Like, Comment) and new row is inserted in that table according to the action and add the action ID in the corresponding field and leave the others null. Then call them combined with the related table, if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Your best bet would be to write queries that populate a second table then query the second table and sort by timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

you can with [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and aliasing:

```
select * from ((select 1 as type,time_added from posts where ...) union (select 2 as type,time_added from likes where ...) ...) order by time_added asc
```

**NOTE**: Column selection must have the same order in regards to the column type.

Do not do:

```
(select 1 as type,time_added from posts where ...) union (select time_added,2 as type from likes where ...)
```

Or if you don`t select the same number of columns in subqueries:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Your result set will be an multi dimensional array as follows:

```
array(array('type'=>1,'time_added'=>'...'),array('type'=>2,'time_added'=>'...'));
```

By **TYPE** you know if it is a post or a like
Hope this helps